# D3 bar chart does not dynamically update y-axis and x-axis properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to dynamically update my bar chart from a json data set.

Data look like this :

[{x=a,y=1},{x=b,y=2},{x=c,y=4}],
 [{x=d,y=0.1},{x=a,y=1}],{x=b,y=4}]

I used the code to set the dimensions of the canvas (y-axis and x-axis):

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

The whole code :

```
    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")


    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10);


    // add the SVG element
    var chart = d3.select(".chart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");






    // load the data
        data=mydata

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.x = d.x;
            d.y = +d.y;
        });

      // scale the range of the data
      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);

      // add axis
      chart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("dx", "-.8em")
          .attr("dy", "-.55em")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

      chart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 5)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Frequency");


      // Add bar chart
      chart.selectAll("bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });


     //Call function to update barchart
      function redraw(data){


          x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);

          chart.select(".x.axis").remove();
        chart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("dx", "-.8em")
          .attr("dy", "-.55em")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );



            // y-axis
            chart.select(".y.axis").remove();
            chart.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .call(yAxis)
              .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Frequency");





            var bar = chart.selectAll(".bar")
                    .data(data, function(d) { 

                        return d.x; });

            // new data:
            bar.enter().append("rect")
               .attr("class", "bar")
               .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
               .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
               .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
               .attr("width", x.rangeBand());


            // removed data:
           // bar.exit().remove();
            chart.select(".y.axis").transition().delay(750).call(yAxis)

            // updated data:
            bar
               .transition()
               .duration(750)
                   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
                   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
      }
```

Comment: You have all the data 'enter' and 'update' on same set? Where you update?

Comment: @klaujesi I am updating the bar chart with a different data set. When the user clicks on a button it calls redraw(new_data_set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you will have to redefine the xAxis and yAxis to use the new scale values you define in the function, by pretty much copying the declaration into the function scope.

```
// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);
```

The primary reason you're getting the old values on the axis is because when you call ".call(xAxis)" inside the function the x scale associated with that axis declaration is the original one.

Hope this helps..

Comment: I tried redeclaring x and y axis in the update function but now it looks like the new graph is behind the old graph. When i hover on the bars I can see the new graph is highlighted with the right value

Comment: It sounds like you may need to remove your old chart prior to drawing the new one. you can use `d3.select('svg').remove();` to remove the svg at the top of your redraw method.

Comment: It still didn't work so I used d3.select('.chart').html("") to clear the chart div and redraw the graph. This worked for me. Thanks for the help